# invalid ELF header error when using nodejs-java on a synology NAS

Tags: java, node.js, linux, elf, synology

I can't run java code on a nodejs app, on a Synology NAS.

When I try to run this code on a test.js file, it gives an error.

var java = require('java');

var javaLangSystem = java.import('java.lang.System');

javaLangSystem.out.printlnSync('Hello World');

The Error: /volume1/server/Serveur_Application_EMASOLAR/node_modules/java/build/Rele         ase/nodejavabridge_bindings.node: invalid ELF header

I've done my research and I know that the error happend when we change the OS. The binary files need to be recompiled. However, a simple npm rebuild didn't solve the problem.

I'm using a DSM 7 on a synology NAS, the terminal is PuTTY.

The Linux Version is Linux 4.4.180+.

Comment: Did you run `npm rebuld` **on the NAS**? A common cause for this is building the binaries on another OS and/or architecture. Your NAS is likely to be ARM based (though Synology also makes x86 ones, IIRC).

Comment: Yes I run npm rebuild on the NAS. But It seems that on the NAS I can't do much : not even a npm install java ...